# How does IIS Process ASP.net MVC request?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a confusion over ASP.net MVC request handled by IIS. As every body says it built on top of ASP.net Engine. So only **Url routing module** and **MvcRouteHandler**  makes a difference and they  handled the request appropriately. I understand this.

But My Question is how IIS understand that it is MVC request . There is no extension like .aspx is given in url . So how does it maps to correct **ISAPI DLL**.

I appreciate your help to clear my confusion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These rules can be defined at any level in IIS. Most MVC applications define the handlers at the application level in the web.config file:

```
<system.webServer>        
    <handlers>
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit".../>
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit".../>
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0".../>
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```